# For nginx, am I listening to port 443 or port 3000 for this url https://localhost:3000?

Tags: django, http, nginx, webserver

I am trying to navigate through the weeds of nginx and reverse proxy passing and one area that I am getting confused on is the port mappings. Here is an example nginx configuration file:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;
    server_name www.domain.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/ubuntu/app/public;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```

What I am specifying here is that my app should listen to port 443 because it has a self signed certificate on it. It won't accept port 80 http but only 443. Here is an example I found about proxy_passing to localhost. Which is what I want to do. Here is the example:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  server.key;
    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    location / {
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_set_header    Host             $host;
      proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-Verify  SUCCESS;
      proxy_set_header    X-Client-DN      $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Subject    $ssl_client_s_dn;
      proxy_set_header    X-SSL-Issuer     $ssl_client_i_dn;
      proxy_read_timeout 1800;
      proxy_connect_timeout 1800;
    }
}
```

Here is what I don't understand and could use some clarification. What port/url am I listening to in the second example? In the server block I see this:

```
    listen       443;
    server_name  localhost;
```

That means we are listening to `localhost` on `443` through https. That is simple enough to understand so far. Now we get to the `location` block.

```
   location / {
      proxy_pass  http://localhost:3000;
```

What is going on here? If I started nginx and typed in the address bar `http:localhost:3000` what is going to happen? Will it fail because I typed in `http`? Shouldn't it have been `https:localhost:3000`? Am I listening on port 80, 443, or 3000?

Also, on a small side question. What would happen if I opened up my Postman application and typed a get request to `http://localhost:3000` or `https://localhost` with the second configuration? Would it hit the nginx server or try to reach my laptop's localhost?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired reference uses the ssl on directive which has been depreciated

Take a look at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl

When you specify which ports to listen on you need to group them by scheme (HTTP|HTTPS)

Example server block would look like

```
server {
    listen 80 http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 http2 default_server;

    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    server_name www.domain.com;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/ubuntu/app/public;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;
}
```